# c# extracting words

Tags: c#

i have following piece of code with me iam spliting the words using only one space and the output is

**output:**

```
when 
ambition
ends
happiness
begins
```

But i want split the words after two spaces i mean my output should be like this:

```
when ambition
ends happiness
begins
```

```
string vj = "when ambiton ends happiness begins";
List<string> k = new List<string>();
char ch = ' ';
string[] arr = vj.Split(ch);
foreach (string r in arr)
{
  Response.Write(r + "<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string vj = "when ambiton ends happiness begins";
List<string> k = new List<string>();
char ch = ' ';
string[] arr = vj.Split(ch);
bool flag=false;

foreach (string r in arr)
{
 if(flag)
    {
    Response.Write(r + "<br/>");
    flag=false;
    }
 else
    { 
    Response.Write(r + " ");
    flag=true;
    }
}
```

The above is good for the case you specified (skipping a single space).

---

Though not necessary, but if you want it all wrapped up, Here :

```
string myString = "when ambiton ends happiness begins";

bool flag=false;

foreach (string item in myString.Split(ch))
         Response.Write(item + flag=!flag?" ":"<br/>");
```

Comment: What is `List<string> k` for? Your variable naming remembered me my  computer science school teacher, who almost screamed at anyone for variables named like a,b,v,... :)

Comment: ... Since you already told the answer.. Why not flag= !flag      ?

Comment: @Kirill - I edited directly in the OP's code. The variable names are not my choice.

Answer (score 2):

As this is marked homework, I will give a hint:

- Keep a counter for how many spaces you *do* want in each line
- Reset this counter when number of spaces is reached
- When number of spaces is reached, add a line break

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with regular expressions:

```
// Loosely: a word, followed by another word if available
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\S+( \S+)?"); 

string[] splits = regex.Matches(inputText)
                       .Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(match => match.Value)
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: sorry its not home work im bit beginner to this and working on data mining project so got stucked here so i needed help.

Comment: @Oren A: Whoops. I began to work on it before the tag was added. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Split it like you do right now, then loop the resulting array and join them all up using a standard `for` loop.

Comment: why create so much work, wen only a small index will suffice?

Comment: @loxxy: Coding wise it's little work, but performance wise I suppose it could be better. Not that I think that performance is an issue here...

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to go manual on this one, searching for the space-character in the string, and keeping a counter. You'll have to remember the indices of the space-characters you'll want to split from, and use the .Substring(startindex, length) method for extracting the separate parts.

Comment: Dunno about that.  The OP has already split it.  Just means the OP has to go two tokens at a time instead of one.  (i.e. Don't use foreach)

Comment: You could of course split them like in the example, and just paste them together again, if you're not afraid of a little extra string creations.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a variable containing start position of words to extract
2. Create a space counter
3. Loop through char by char (using an indexer)
4. When the number of spaces equals two, call substring method from position saved in #1 to current index.
5. Change variable from #1 to the current index.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a bool indicating whether or not you should add "/br", call it breakLine.
Now at each iteration check if it's true - if so add "/br", otherwise don't. finally negate it at each iteration.
Implementation is left as an exercise (-: